# Tensorflow GAN estimator hang while evaluating

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I implement GAN in Tensorflow Estimator format. Here's the complete code in [gist](https://gist.github.com/litaxc/0515e9c3007176ff97c0da41c4a6e229).

The model can be trained normally. However, it seems to hang at `model.evaluate` forever. The log after training is like below.

```
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2018-12-03-02:19:06
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
2018-12-03 02:19:06.956750: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-12-03 02:19:06.956781: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-12-03 02:19:06.956786: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0
2018-12-03 02:19:06.956790: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N
2018-12-03 02:19:06.956912: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 10464 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tensorlog/wad/acgan/a51fbd6/model.ckpt-10002
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
```

If I use `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate`, the evaluated accuracy will always be 0.5.

I've already checked my tfrecords file and it's not empty, images and labels can be read without problem. I also tried using same tfrecords file for both training and evaluating but still got the same result.

It seems to me that the tensorflow model may have problem loading GAN's weights from checkpoints. If it's true, how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it's because the `training` parameters in `dropout` and `batch_normalization` prevent the weights from restoration.
Fix the value of training to either true or false solve the problem.